# What's the direction of the current in this circle if a magnet is approaching (or distancing from) the circle?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

I'm not a native speaker so I don't know how to properly describe the problem I'm having right now

We got a circuit, it's a circle, and it's placed at the left. We also have a bar magnet which is either approaching the circle (or distancing from the circle)

[image]

And we have to find out which situation is true. I know that it's b), that if you approach this circle with S, you get a current whose direction is clockwise.

But **why** is it so? Is it because of some equations? Or can we draw/visualize the solution?

Comment: Especially this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/200027/63690

Comment: yes, thanks you !